# Error applying function in grouped tibble

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a function that takes a current balance and then works backwards monthly to calculate prior month end balances from each month's additions and losses. The balances need to be calculated within combinations of variables. The output I want looks like this - month_end_balance is what I want the function to output. Everything else I have.

| type | service | month_starting | add | loss | current_balance | month_end_balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Luxury | 12/1/21 | 2 | 1 | 20 | 20 |
| A | Luxury | 11/1/21 | 4 | 7 | NA | 19 |
| A | Luxury | 10/1/21 | 0 | 0 | NA | 22 |
| B | Economy | 12/1/21 | 2 | 8 | 50 | 50 |
| B | Economy | 11/1/21 | 4 | 2 | NA | 56 |
| B | Economy | 10/1/21 | 0 | 0 | NA | 54 |

I created the following function, which works on ungrouped data.

```
running_balance_4 <- function(current_balance, add, loss) {
  out <- rep(NA, length(current_balance))
  out[[1]] <- current_balance[[1]]
  for (i in 2:(length(current_balance))) {
    out[[i]] <-  out[[(i-1)]] - add[[(i-1)]] + loss[[(i-1)]]
  }
  out
}
```

But I can't get it to apply within each group. It might just be a syntax issue.

```
df %>%
  group_by(type, service) %>%
  arrange(type, service, desc(month_starting)) %>%
  group_modify(running_balance_4(current_balance, add, loss))
```

Appreciate any help with the syntax and/or the function itself.

Update: when I attempt to run it I get the following error message: object 'current_balance' not found. So I think there may be a syntax error in addition to any issues with the function.

Comment: From `?group_modify`, *"`group_modify()` is good for "data frame in, data frame out"... `.f` must return a data frame."* Your function doesn't return a data frame, nor does it work on `.x` the sub data frame. Could you demonstrate how your function work on ungrouped data?

Comment: @GregorThomas thank you for responding. I have also attempted with group_map, which I thought did not have that issue. If I just run the function directly I get output, just not the desired output, since the balance does not reset for each combination of variables. But test_function <- running_balance_4(df$current_balance, df$add, df$loss) produces correct math as output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see in the comments you got your function to work. However, I thought you might want to see a solution using built in R functions rather than applying a grouped function.

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

df <- tribble(
  ~type,  ~service, ~month_starting,  ~add, ~loss,  ~current_balance,
  "A", "Luxury",   "12/1/21", 2,  1,  20,
  "A", "Luxury",   "11/1/21", 4,  7,  NA,
  "A", "Luxury",   "10/1/21", 0,  0,  NA,
  "B", "Economy",  "12/1/21", 2,  8,  50,
  "B", "Economy",  "11/1/21", 4,  2,  NA,
  "B", "Economy",  "10/1/21", 0,  0,  NA 
)

df %>% 
  # Two temporary columns to calculate with.
  mutate(
    # Replace current balance with 0 to work with cumulative sum.
    c_balance = coalesce(current_balance, 0),
    # Add the loss and subtract the add since we are working backwards.
    monthly = c_balance + loss - add
  ) %>%
  arrange(type, service, desc(month_starting)) %>%
  group_by(type, service) %>%
  # Taking the lag will put NA on the first element (the rows with current_balance)
  # cumsum is a built in cumulative sum
  mutate(monthly = lag(cumsum(monthly))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(month_end_balance = pmax(current_balance, monthly, na.rm = T))  %>%
  select(-c_balance, -monthly)
```

It makes a difference based off of the `current_balance`, does a cumulative sum of that difference using `cumsum`, and then lines up the observation using `lag`. The output you were after can then be found by the maximum between `current_balance` and the lagged variable, since all of the values you don't want are `NA`.

```
# A tibble: 6 × 7
  type  service month_starting   add  loss current_balance month_end_balance
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>          <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>             <dbl>
1 A     Luxury  12/1/21            2     1              20                20
2 A     Luxury  11/1/21            4     7              NA                19
3 A     Luxury  10/1/21            0     0              NA                22
4 B     Economy 12/1/21            2     8              50                50
5 B     Economy 11/1/21            4     2              NA                56
6 B     Economy 10/1/21            0     0              NA                54
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear and smart solution here. I should mention your explanation also helped solve my more beginner issue of not knowing how to use my function within the grouped table. I thought I needed to use 'group_modify' or 'group_map' but kept getting errors - I still don't completely understand why. But mutate(running_balance_4(current_balance, add, loss)) seems to have also worked.